# Same height and width for cells in grid layout android/kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, android-gridlayout

How do I get a recycler view with a gridlayout where every cells have the same cell width and cell height dependent to the screen width.

I set my layout like this

```
linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
categoriesRecyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this,4)
```

and I got always 4 cells in a row.

The result looks like this.

[image]

I understand why I got this result. I set my content inside the cells always to `wrap_content`. So when the image is bigger or the the text is longer the height will change.

My layout is defined like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_image_view">
```

`rounded_image_view` is just a shape.

I thought that I could regulate the constraint layout with help of the ratio.

Some other things I tried: Use cards, use linear layout, put the content inside a `View`, worked with `constraintHeight_percent` and I read a lot in similar threads like this. But I didn't get a solution.

The full xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_image_view">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/categoryImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/itemTitle"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/anatomie" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Anatomie"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/categoryImage" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/isPremiumImage"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/locked" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically calculate the width of the device screen and set the height of the item view accordingly.

Add the below util method for calculating size to your adapter class.

```
     /**
     * calculates the size of the item based on the screen size
     */
    fun calculateSizeOfView(context: Context): Int {

        val displayMetrics = context.resources.displayMetrics
        val dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels
        return (dpWidth / COLUMN_COUNT) // COLUMN_COUNT would be 4 in your case
    }
```

Now add the below lines of code inside onCreateViewHolder method of your adapter class.

1) get the size of each item from the util method

2) create layout params - both height and width as above calculated value

3) set the params to your inflated view inside the OnCreateViewHolder

```
val view = *your_inflated_view* // the return view of your .inflate method
val size = calculateSizeOfView(*your_context*)

val margin = 8 * 4 // any vertical spacing margin = your_margin * column_count 
val layoutParams = GridLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams(size - margin, size)) // width and height

layoutParams.bottomMargin = 8 // horizontal spacing if needed

view.layoutParams = layoutParams

return *your_view_holder_with_view* // usual return
```